# Join two tables and merge text values in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables which you can also find in the `sql fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/493617/7):

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Sales_Date DATE,
    Product TEXT,
    Sales_Channel TEXT,
    Sales_Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Sales
(Sales_Date, Product, Sales_Channel, Sales_Quantity)
VALUES 
("2017-05-23", "Product A", "Online", "400"),
("2018-09-10", "Product A", "Store", "200"),
("2018-12-14", "Product B", "Store", "600"),
("2019-01-03", "Product B", "Store", "700"),
("2019-02-15", "Product B", "Online", "650"),
("2019-03-20", "Product A", "Online", "380"),
("2019-08-25", "Product C", "TradeFair", "120"),
("2019-09-16", "Product C", "Online", "470"),
("2019-09-16", "Product A", "Store", "920"),
("2019-10-20", "Product B", "TraidFair", "860"),
("2020-01-03", "Product B", "TradeFair", "610");


CREATE TABLE Purchasing (
    Purchasing_Date VARCHAR(255),
    Product TEXT,
    Purchasing_Channel TEXT,
    Purchasing_Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Purchasing
(Purchasing_Date, Product, Purchasing_Channel, Purchasing_Quantity)
VALUES 
("2017-01-10", "Product A", "Local_Supplier", "1000"),
("2017-01-16", "Product A", "Local_Supplier", "3000"),
("2017-01-19", "Product B", "Reseller", "1500"),
("2018-05-14", "Product B", "Reseller", "4500"),
("2018-05-14", "Product C", "Foreign_Import", "1800"),
("2019-04-16", "Product C", "Foreign_Import", "2300");
```

**NOTE:** Each product is assigned explicitly to one purchasing channel!

---

Now, I want to make a query which gives me the following result:

```
Sales_Date   Product      Channel                   Sales_Quantity
2017-05-23   Product A    Online_Local_Supplier     400 
2018-09-10   Product A    Store_Local_Supplier      200
2018-12-14   Product B    Store_Reseller            600
2019-01-03   Product B    Store_Reseller            650
:            :            :                         :
:            :            :                         :
:            :            :                         :
```

As you can see I want to merge the `Sales_Channel` and the `Purchasing_Channel` in one column. 
Therefore, I set up the following query:

```
SELECT 
s.Sales_Date, 
s.Product, 
(Case sales_channel
 When "Online" Then "Online"
 When "Store" then "Store"
 When "TradeFair" then "Traidfair"
 ELSE "NoSalesChannel"
 END) AS Channel,
s.Sales_Quantity
FROM Sales s
JOIN Purchasing p ON p.Product = s.Product
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

This query inserts the `Sales_Channel` correctly but how do I have to change it so the `Purchasing_Channel` is added to it as displayed in my desired result?

Comment: Why JOIN Purchasing, when no p column seems to be involved?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no set functions are involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `distinct`:

```
SELECT distinct
s.Sales_Date, 
s.Product, 
concat(s.Sales_Channel, '_', p.Purchasing_Channel) as Chanel,
s.Sales_Quantity
FROM Sales s
JOIN Purchasing p ON p.Product = s.Product
```

Try `concat` and `group by`.

```
SELECT 
s.Sales_Date, 
s.Product, 
concat(s.Sales_Channel, '_', p.Purchasing_Channel) as Chanel,
s.Sales_Quantity
FROM Sales s
JOIN Purchasing p ON p.Product = s.Product
group by s.Sales_Date, 
s.Product,
concat(s.Sales_Channel, '_', p.Purchasing_Channel),
s.Sales_Quantity
```

This will give you a result:

```
Sales_Date  | Product   | Chanel                 | Sales_Quantity

2017-05-23    Product A   Online_Local_Supplier    400
2018-09-10    Product A   Store_Local_Supplier     200
2018-12-14    Product B   Store_Reseller           600
2019-01-03    Product B   Store_Reseller           700
2019-02-15    Product B   Online_Reseller          650
2019-03-20    Product A   Online_Local_Supplier    380
2019-08-25    Product C   TradeFair_Foreign_Import 120
2019-09-16    Product C   Online_Foreign_Import    470
2019-09-16    Product A   Store_Local_Supplier     920
2019-10-20    Product B   TraidFair_Reseller       860
```

P.S. Please do check all the comments jarlh has given you.

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b03a17a56a0fb16ab056ef3d324a39ce)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca3c01/3